# Is it possible to get anchors working correctly with the back button in this snippet?

Tags: html, css

I have this code which gives you a page with a black menu bar at the top of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            overflow:hidden;
        }
        #menubar {
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            background-color:black;
            height: 60px;
            width:100%;
            box-shadow: 0 3px 3px #ccc;
        }
        #mainbody {
            position:absolute;
            top:60px;
            height:calc(100% - 60px);
            overflow:auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="menubar"></div>
    <div id="mainbody">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#paragraph1">Paragraph 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph2">Paragraph 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph3">Paragraph 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph4">Paragraph 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph5">Paragraph 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph6">Paragraph 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph7">Paragraph 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph8">Paragraph 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="#paragraph9">Paragraph 9</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            <a name="paragraph1"></a>
            <h2>Paragraph 1</h2>
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
        </p>
        <p>
            <a name="paragraph2"></a>
            <h2>Paragraph 2</h2>
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
        </p>
        <p>
            <a name="paragraph3"></a>
            <h2>Paragraph 3</h2>
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
        </p>
        <p>
            <a name="paragraph4"></a>
            <h2>Paragraph 4</h2>
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
        </p>
        <p>
            <a name="paragraph5"></a>
            <h2>Paragraph 5</h2>
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
        </p>
        <p>
            <a name="paragraph6"></a>
            <h2>Paragraph 6</h2>
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
        </p>
        <p>
            <a name="paragraph7"></a>
            <h2>Paragraph 7</h2>
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
        </p>
        <p>
            <a name="paragraph8"></a>
            <h2>Paragraph 8</h2>
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
        </p>
        <p>
            <a name="paragraph9"></a>
            <h2>Paragraph 9</h2>
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
            jdh auio chasuif shuiv hseduv hsduv hduiv hdv hdfuvh df v
        </p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

It almost works 100% correctly except that if you click one of the anchor links at the top, whilst it takes you to the correct point in the document, the back button doesn't then do anything (I would expect it to go back to the previous place in the document that it was at, as would normally happen with anchors).

How would I get the back button to work as expected?

Comment: Do you mean browsers back button?

Comment: It seems to be the `position: absolute` on `#mainbody` that breaks the back button. Remove this and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/yb83mndj/2/

Comment: Where is your back button?

Comment: I assume OP is talking about the browsers back button.